# Setting value for nsmutabledictionary in multi levels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to set a key for UserName as with respect to this code:

```
{
"CustomerAccount":{
"UserName":"String content"
};
```

I am trying to set the username here, does anyone know how can I set a name in dictionary with levels?

My code is as:

```
[mutabledictionary setObject:self.uitextfield.text forKey:UserName];
```

however this sets the username below to CustomerAccount not insider CustomerAccount.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a sub-dictionary, like this:

```
NSDictionary *userAccount = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"String Content" forKey:@"UserName"];
NSMutableArray *accounts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:userAccount];

// do something with accounts
NSLog(@"%@", accounts);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the two level mutable dictionary already exists (its not clear from your question) you need to send your *setObject:forKey* message to the second level dictionary, like so:

```
[[mutabledictionary objectForKey:@"CustomerAccount"] setObject:self.uitextfield.text forKey:UserName];
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

Answer (score 0):

Just create create array of CustomerAccount and use in NSDictionary. Use

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```